ArgoCD image auto image updater commit message based on triggering commit
My current flow is this:

On merge to master branch, build and push a new docker image.
ArgoCD auto image updater detects a new image, and commits an update to the deployments repository.
ArgoCD detects the change in the deployments repo and syncs a new version.

What I want is that the commit by the image updater will be descriptive, and contain the commit message from the original commit merged to master.
I see in the docs the option to modify the message, but it looks like I only have access to the SHA - can I access more things from the original commit?
